# Create a mapping in .vimrc that accepts an argument

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, regular-expression, substitute

I want to create a mapping in my .vimrc file that takes an argument.

I'm constantly defining latex commands which require arguments inside of curly brackets and writing them instead inside regular parens, e.g., writing `\interior(x_y^z)` when I meant to write `interior{x_y_z}`.    If I know the name of the function, it's trivial, i.e.,

```
:g/interior(\(.*\))/s//interior{\1}/g
```

But I want to create a mapping to which I could feed the name of function, e.g., `interior`. It might look something like this, where `myWord` is the argument.

```
:map ;subst   :g/<myWord>(\(.*\))/s//<myWord>{\1}/g
```

and I would call it with something like `;subst <myWord>`

I presume I have to use something like `:noremap` but the examples on this forum are always much more complicated than I can follow.

Comment: You probably want `:h user-commands`, not a mapping.

Comment: Nitpick: The name macro in Vim typically refers to [recording](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#recording) into a register with the `q` command and replaying it with `@`. What you're describing here is typically referred to as a [mapping](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#mapping). Would you consider to [edit] the question and use the term "mapping" rather than "macro"? I think that would improve the question. Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden done ;)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Taking a word or otherwise long argument (longer than a single char) from a mapping usually involves prompting the user, using the [`input()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#input%28%29) function.

But that's often not very convenient, as you're somewhat slowed down by the prompting and it's also hard to invoke or reuse that mapping from a non-interactive context.

You'll probably find that using a user-defined command is typically a more handy way to expose features that take longer arguments.

In any case, let's create both.

Let's actually start by writing a function to perform the substitution, including the arbitrary word. Even if we didn't make the function public, it would make implementing either the mapping or the user-command easier.

```
function! SubstBrackets(word)
    let word_re = '\V'.escape(a:word, '/\')
    let pattern = '\v<('.word_re.'\v)\((.{-})\)'
    execute '%s/'.pattern.'/\1{\2}/eg'
endfunction
```

This function is a somewhat more sophisticated way to perform the substitution you described. It uses "very magic" and "very nomagic" mode together with `escape()` to ensure special characters in the word will not interfere.

It will also match the word at a word boundary (the `<` at the start of the match, you might have seen it as `\<` before, but we're in "very magic" mode here.) It matches the terms inside parens using non-greedy `.{-}` match to find the nearest closing paren. Finally, it uses two capturing groups, so the word doesn't need to be repeated on the replacement side.

You can test it with:

```
:call SubstBrackets('interior')
```

(We could go a step further in sophistication here by making `SubstBrackets` a "range" function, rather than implicitly acting on `%` for the whole buffer. See [`:help :func-range`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Afunc-range) for more details on implementing a range function.)

At this point, we can implement our `;subst` mapping using this function, using:

```
nnoremap <silent> ;subst :call SubstBrackets(
  \ input('Word to replace? ', 'interior'))<CR>
```

One downside of this mapping is that typing `;subst` possibly without visual feedback can be awkward. If you type a single character incorrectly, you can't fix it with "backspace" either, you need to break execution of the macro altogether (with Ctrl+C or similar), then start again.

I briefly discussed how `input()` can be awkward in interrupting the flow with a prompt and also making it hard to reuse this mapping in a less interactive context. On the upside, `input()` lets you easily define a default text to use if user simply presses "enter", which can be nice too... (`input()` also allows you to specify how to do completion of the term you're typing, which can be useful too!)

Now I mentioned creating a user-defined command was a possibly better interface for this feature. This is how you would define one:

```
command! -bar -nargs=1 SubstBrackets
  \ call SubstBrackets(<q-args>)
```

And then you can use it with:

```
:SubstBrackets interior
```

Note that you can use tab completion here, so you can simply type `:Su<Tab>` and Vim will complete the command for you!

This interface tends to be better, since you can use this command from many other contexts, such as functions or `if` or `for` statements, etc.

Same as with `input()`, you can specify a completion type to use with the argument of this function. So even though you don't get the descriptive prompt, you do get one of the other benefits of `input()` here.

You could also implement a default value, by using `-nargs=*` and changing the function to take variable number of arguments, then checking the number of passed parameters and using a default if none was passed. (In fact, that also allows you to receive multiple arguments, which you could also handle by substituting bracket types in *all* passed words!)

Let's also explore allowing a range to be passed here. By turning the function into a `range` function and passing a [`-range=%`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-range) to the command definition, we can take an optional range, while still acting on the whole buffer if no range is passed.

Here's a modified complete version of the command, that takes an optional range:

```
function! SubstBrackets(word) range
    let word_re = '\V'.escape(a:word, '/\')
    let pattern = '\v<('.word_re.'\v)\((.{-})\)'
    let range = a:firstline.','.a:lastline
    execute range.'s/'.pattern.'/\1{\2}/eg'
endfunction

command! -bar -nargs=1 -range=% SubstBrackets
  \ <line1>,<line2>call SubstBrackets(<q-args>)
```

Hopefully I've successfully demonstrated how and why the user-defined command version of this feature is the most flexible and usable one!

Comment: Fabulous, thanks much @filbranden  Two questions: 1)I couldn't make `range` work: I tried `:SubstBrackets -range=13,15 myWord` where on lines 13 and 16 I had `myWord(X)`, and hoped the mapping would just operate on line 13, but it didn't change anything. 2) There are many parens in the construction & I couldn't figure out which were the pair that matched those in my expr. I tried constructing a new command `substParens` that went in the reverse direction:  on the `let pattern` line, I changed `((.{-})\)` to `({.{-}}\)` & on the `execute` line I changed `\1{\2}` to `\1(\2)' but it didnt work

Comment: @LeoSimon 1) The range comes at the start of the command, so `:13,15SubstBrackets myWord`. The `-range` syntax is only for *defining* the command.

Comment: @LeoSimon The literal parens are the ones escaped with `\`s. So you should.replace `\((.{-})\)` with `\{(.{-})\}` on the pattern side. (See `:help /\v` to see how "verymagic" works.)

Comment: @filebranden     Thanks very much for the clarifications!  I've learned a great deal from this.    And I absolutely promise this will be the last followup request.    Playing around I realized it would be prudent to add a "confirm" option, as in `g/myWord(X)/s//myWord{X}/gc`   Is there a way to add that option?

Comment: @LeoSimon To always have it confirm, just change the end of the `execute` line from `/eg'` to `/egc'`. If you want that to be conditional (for example, `:SubstBrackets -confirm interior`) then it's a somewhat larger modification, but doable... Just make your command use `-nargs=*`, your function take multiple arguments and use a `for` loop in your function to check for a "-confirm" or similar argument.

Comment: I suggest you try by yourself (better way to learn!) but if you get stuck ask a separate question, such as "How to handle an optional argument in a user-defined command?" This answer is long enough already, so discussing that separately on its own question would be best! Cheers!

Comment: Ah, that was really dumb of me, should have seen that myself....     thanks

Comment: @LeoSimon Not dumb at all! Don't bring yourself down.